# jquery addclass/removeclass doesn't always work when "speed" is set (mouse events)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

In css class "employee_mouseover" I make the bg color red.

```
        $(".employee").bind("mouseenter", function() {
            $(this).addClass("employee_mouseover");
        });
        $(".employee").bind("mouseleave", function() {
            $(this).removeClass("employee_mouseover");
        });
```

This works fine.

But, when I set a speed to make it look more pretty, the element stays red when I quickly do a mouseenter+mouseleave;

```
    $(".employee").bind("mouseenter", function() {
        $(this).addClass("employee_mouseover", "fast");
    });
    $(".employee").bind("mouseleave", function() {
        $(this).removeClass("employee_mouseover", "fast");
    });
```

This doesn't work well, unless I move in and out of the element very slowly.

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I didn't even know that removeClass and addClass accepted a 2nd parameter with a speed.

Comment: how can you remove a class slowly?

Comment: maybe jquery was smart enough to execute the css changes effect slowly?

Comment: the `duration` paramater is jQuery UI-specific, the tags on this question have been updated accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done, but you need to install the [jquery coloranimate plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color). Then you can use the code below to change the color slowly:

```
$(".employee").bind("mouseenter", function() {
  $(this).animate({backgroundColor: "#bbccff"}, "slow");

});
$(".employee").bind("mouseleave", function() {
  $(this).animate({backgroundColor: "white"}, "slow");
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this constructive answer. The other replies were helpful as well in an educational way, but this one gave me a way to achieve what I was trying to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

from the [jQuery UI docs](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/ClassTransitions):

> The jQuery UI effects core extends the base class API to be able to animate between two different classes. The following methods are changed. They now accept three additional parameters: speed, easing (optional), and callback.

So @Thomas must have included both jQuery and jQuery UI libraries on his page, enabling the speed and callback parameters to addClass and removeClass.

Answer (score 3):

You're using the wrong event.  You want:

```
$(".employee").hover(function() {
 $(this).addClass("employee_mouseover");
}, function() {
 $(this).removeClass("employee_mouseover");
});
```

And there's no speed argument on add or remove class.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, do it in CSS!

```
.employee:hover{background:pink;}
```

Also, [there is no speed parameted for addClass](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/addClass), speed only exists for effects.

Comment: That doesn't enable me to set the speed to make it look pretty, no?
Besides, I need to enable/disable the mouse events sometimes when the user does stuff..

Comment: "Also, there is no speed parameted for addClass, speed only exists for effects."
That doesn't seem to be true, as it works when I do it slowly.

I described both of these things in my original post.

Comment: @Thomas: actually it's very true.

Comment: @Thomas: It works, but it's apparently an undocumented feature that doesn't work correctly.

Comment: It can't possibly work at all. A class is something an element either has or does not have; there is no in-between state like a tweened position or blended colour possible. Whatever you're seeing, it's not a slow class transition.

Comment: @R.Bemrose: No, there is no such feature. jQuery trunk confirms addClass/removeClass are synchronous operations: http://dev.jquery.com/browser/trunk/jquery/src/core.js

Comment: Thanks for researching this. What's weird tho is intellisense in visual studio 2008 told me that the second parameter to be passed to addClass() is the "speed". I wonder why they've put that in (AND made it work) without specifying this on the jquery site

Comment: Microsoft strikes again. Turn off the quite-poorly-named 'intellisense' and always go by the real documentation.

Comment: Actually, I think the intellisense file I use is third party made.
Next to that, this is the first time in 3 years of heavily using intellsense that I found a mistake in it..

Answer (score 2):

There is a duration parameter for removeClass (http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/removeClass), but it is not working in FF. Is there anything wrong with my code? I am new to JQuery. I am going to try animate function now.

What I am trying to do here is use the anchors and then highlight the destination anchor location when the anchor is clicked.
Here's my HTML code -

```
<ul>
                <li><a href="#caricatures">Caricatures</a></li>
                <li><a href="#sketches">Sketches</a></li>
</ul>
```

My destination anchor is -

```
<a href="#" id="caricatures"><h3>Caricatures</h3></a>
```

This is where I might the background color to change.

Here's my CSS -

```
<style>
            .spotlight{
                background-color:#fe5;
            }
</style>
```

Here's my JQuery code -

```
<script>
    $('a[href$="caricatures"]').click(function(){
        $('a[id="caricatures"] h3').addClass("spotlight");
        $('a[id="caricatures"] h3').removeClass("spotlight",1000);
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: I read the animate() method documentation (http://api.jquery.com/animate/) and it says - "width, height, or left can be animated but background-color cannot be.". That's why my .animate() wasn't working. switchClass doesn't work either. And I do not want to toggleClass.

Comment: A correction to my above comment - I tried animating backgroundColor in another example and it had worked. It just struck me and hence this new comment. So now I am confused why the documentation said that background color won't work. Do they mean to say "background-color" won't work, but "backgroundColor" does?

Comment: I could finally make my code work. Thanks everyone for your responses. I added just one more line to my code - I included "jquery-ui-1.8.6.custom.min.js" script file and my above code works perfectly fine. There is no mention about including this script in the documentation/examples for addClass (http://api.jquery.com/addClass/). I did not realize that it was part of JQuery UI.

Answer (score 1):

`addClass` is for adding CSS classes to elements. If you're looking to change some CSS property by tweening, then you need to do that explicitly using [Effects](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects).

Your code:

```
$(this).addClass("employee_mouseover", "fast");
```

Will add two classes, `employee_mouseover` and `fast` to `this`, which is obviously not what you're after.

Comment: Think you pasted the wrong code there. Also, "fast" is ignored.

Comment: Wow you are totally right. So it is. :) Guess it's a comma-delimited string instead then.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my transition with jQuery:

```
$("#layoutControl .actionList").click(
    function(){
        $("#assetsContainer").fadeOut("fast",function(){
            $(this).removeClass("assetsGrid").addClass("assetsList");
            $("#iconList").attr("src", "/img/bam/listIcon.png");
            $("#iconGrid").attr("src", "/img/bam/gridIconDim.png");
            $(this).fadeIn("fast");
        });
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Also, there is no speed parameted for addClass, speed only exists for effects.**

Correct.

But perhaps this Plugin might help:

[animate-to-class](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/animate-to-class)

Answer (score 0):

Even if you include JqueryUI properly, these all appear to fail outside of FF when you use the "duration" parameter. Causes JS errors in IE. I would stick to animate() which sucks.

http://jqueryui.com/docs/addClass/

http://jqueryui.com/docs/removeClass/

http://jqueryui.com/docs/switchClass/

http://jqueryui.com/docs/toggleClass/

There is no note of this in the docs on the jqueryui site.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".employee").hover(function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "#bbccff" }, "slow");
}, function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "white" }, "slow");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS3 transitions to achieve this effect.

```
a:hover {
    color: red;
    -webkit-transition: 1s color linear;
    -moz-transition: 1s color linear;
}

a:link, a:visited {
    color: white;
    -webkit-transition: 1s color linear;
    -moz-transition: 1s color linear;
}
```