# Adding action to a delete event in jQuery

Tags: jquery, class

How can you add the class `red` to the class `question_body` when the question is removed?

JS in HEAD,

```
jQuery('a.delete_question').live('click', function(){

    jQuery.post('/codes/handlers/delete_a_question.php', 
        { question_id: jQuery(this).attr('rel') }, 
        function(){
            $(.question_body).addClass("red");       // problem here
            alert ("Question was removed");
        })
});
```

The following URL generated by PHP should activate the action,

```
echo ("<a href='#'"
        . "class='dulete_question'"
        . " rel='" . $answer_id . "'>flag</a>"
    );
```

The problem is similar [as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/607386/jquery-addclass-removeclass-doesnt-always-work-when-speed-is-set-mouse-events). It suggests me that `addClass` -command should be correct and that the problem is in the use of it inside the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
 $(.question_body).addClass("red");
```

To this:

```
 $(".question_body").addClass("red");
```

Also make sure you have a CSS class called "red" defined.

You can test this by moving the alert to before the addClass line, rather than after it.